# How to update tool tip content when grid store is update?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs3, extjs-grid

I have this.mygrid there is column as `my_col_id` i want to add tool tip in to the grid cell. I added tool tip for grid cell but that tool tip not update with my store(`my_store`) changes. how to update my grid tool tip when store update

Note: don't work when i added colName.render in to the store update method

```
initComponent{
    colName = this.mygrid.getColumnModel().getColumnById('my_col_id');
    colName.renderer  = this.addToolTip;
}    
   addToolTip : function(value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
      metadata.attr = 'ext:qtip="' + record.get('PRICE')+'<br>'+record.get('DATE') + '"';
      return value;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this.

```
    initComponent : function() {
        this.setTooltip(column);
    },
    setTooltip: function(col) {      
        var originalRenderer = col.renderer;
        col.renderer = function(value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
            meta.attr = 'ext:qtip="' + 'your message' + '"';
            return (originalRenderer ? originalRenderer(value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, field) : value); 
        }         
    }
```

Comment: in the `originalRenderer(value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, field)` what is filed mean with that pram gave to me error as server request fail. with out that gave to me tool tip don't update after edit row